# opencv compiling error ippicv

Tags: compiling, 15.10, opencv

When I write this to terminal:

```
g++ LATCH_match.cpp -std=c++11 $(pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs)
```

I've got an error like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lippicv
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried a lot of things but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: It's probably because your opencv was compiled without -DWITH_IPP=ON option. Recompile it with this option

Comment: I have already tried that.

Comment: And did you also installed it after compilation? Have you checked if this lib was successfully built? Did you tell the compiler where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have verified that installation was made after compilation, then you can update pkgconfig for opencv `(/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc)` to include 3rd party. Use below as a guide to update it

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
libdir3rd=${exec_prefix}/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 3.1.0
Libs: -L${libdir} -L${libdir3rd} -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lippicv -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -lopencv_ts
Libs.private: -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Test -lQt5Concurrent -lQt5OpenGL -lwebp -lpng -lz -ltiff -ljasper -ljpeg -lImath -lIlmImf -lIex -lHalf -lIlmThread -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstapp-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstriff-1.0 -lgstpbutils-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -ldc1394 -lv4l1 -lv4l2 -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale -lavresample -lgphoto2 -lgphoto2_port -lexif -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt -lGLU -lGL -ltbb -latomic
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have precisely the same problem. I did recompile with `-DWITH_IPP=ON`, and there are no build error, or install errors. It looks like the installer put libippicv at the following path:

```
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a
```

But then the installed file `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc` just references `-lippicv`, WITHOUT giving the correct path. So I think something is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a symbolic link in /lib directory to work around it:

```
cd /lib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a libippicv.a
```

(assuming your library is in `/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib`)